# Can't pass options to "DEL" from package.json script

Tags: windows, yarnpkg

Windows 11, Yarn 3.2.4

My `package.json` has this

```json
  "scripts": {
    "predist": "del /Q \"WWW\\*\"",
```

Trying to run it gives this:

```
PS C:\MyProject> yarn predist
Could Not Find C:\/Q
C:\MyProject\WWW\*, Are you sure (Y/N)?
```

If I omit the `/Q` files are deleted as expected once I answer the confirmation prompt

How to stop the `/Q` being interpreted as a filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rimraf` solves this completely. https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf

```
> yarn add --dev rimraf

"predist": "rimraf WWW/*",
```